# JetBrains Rider exclude Unity projects from solution-wide code analysis

Tags: unity-game-engine, analysis, jetbrains-ide, rider

When I launch **Rider 2020.3** with my **Unity 2020** project the solution-wide code analysis reports 3.5K files as having warnings or errors. This makes the analysis practically useless.

How can I restrict Rider to only analyze my code?

I've tried going into "Settings > Editor > Inspection Settings", however the "Exclude Files and Folders" section doesn't seem to work. When I try to add a path it doesn't show up in the list.

When I open the project in Visual Studio with the ReSharper extension It allows me to exclude folders there, it also correctly loads the .DotSettings file next to the solution while Rider does not.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Unity registry packages?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't the best solution, but I ended up recording a macro of clicking on the next warning button, then using the shortcut ctrl-alt-shift-8 to excluded the file.
I left that running for a few minutes until it hit every file.
Then I had to manually go back in to my code files that had warnings and use the shortcut again to re-enable them.

I'm hoping the Rider Unity plugin will eventually be smart enough to know that we don't care about warnings in Unity's code.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the **Elements to Skip** under **Inspection Settings**:

Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) → Editor → Inspection Settings

Under **File masks**, append these three lines:

- `**\Library\**`
- `**\Assets\Plugins\**`
- `**\Packages\**`

This excluded all my non-project specific files from the analysis. Depending on what plugins or assets you use, you might have to include some additional ones.

[image]